# fetch all object from coredata in one-to-many relationship

Tags: objective-c, database, core-data

This is my `Exercise` class

```
@class Question;

@interface Exercise : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * aID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *listQuestion;
@end

@interface Exercise (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addListQuestionObject:(Question *)value;
- (void)removeListQuestionObject:(Question *)value;
- (void)addListQuestion:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeListQuestion:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

and here is `Question` class

```
@class Exercise;

@interface Question : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * aID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id jsAnswer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Exercise *exercise;

@end
```

These class were created by coredata
How can I get all `Question` object via `listQuestion` in each Exercise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give you an array of all Question objects for given exercise:

```
NSArray *questions = [[exercise listQuestion] allObjects];
```